# How to select date in Datepicker using selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

i want to know how we can select element for start date and end date in a datepicker.
I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.add-on > i.enticon-calendar")).click();    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sizcache0696532219872199']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[7]")).click();
```

but it did not find the the second element with sizcache0696532219872199.

How can i select End date and Start date?please any help, thank you.

here is html code:

```
<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label">

        StartDate

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date datepicker-start" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
            <input class="span2 start-date" type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="start"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label">

        EndDate

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date datepicker-end" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="">
            <input class="span2 end-date" type="text" value="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="end"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these selectors:

```
//Should perfom click on i in start date picker
driver.findElement(By.Css(".datepicker-start .enticon-calendar")).Click();

//Same for end date
driver.findElement(By.Css(".datepicker-end .enticon-calendar")).Click();
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: Nice job, Andrey Egorov, it's working for me, thank you very much

Comment: The click on start date and end date are working well and i can choose the date. but when execute for the second time, it did not find element for the date i mean the day of the month, it's weird. i try like this: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".datepicker-start .enticon-calendar")).click(); and then i pick a date like this :  driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]")).click();